# youtube-dl in a javascript script errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

i have youtube-dl in a javascript script ,trying to download hundreds of caption files. I am getting errors

I have a javascript script. I am trying to download ~800 caption files using youtube-dl, i'm getting time out errors and it isn't downloading the files. It seems like it is moving too fast for my computer. I need help pausing the task until the download finishes and then starting the next one.

It is working very less data in videos array.

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');

// var fields = ["youtube_id", "title", "date", "duration", "captioned", "views"];

var videos = [
// More objects ~800+
];
 for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) { 

    var v = videos[i];
    var url = 'https://youtu.be/';
    var options = {};

    if (v["captioned"] == 'No') { 
      var url = url + v["youtube_id"];

      console.log(url);
      var options = {
        auto: true,
        all: false,
        lang: 'en',
        cwd: __dirname + "/auto_generated_captions",
      };
              youtubedl.getSubs(url, options, function(err, files) {
                console.log("did i get here?");
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('subtitle files downloaded:', files);
              });

    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You download too much data at the same time. Try to control the concurrency flow with promise library like bluebird:

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
var promise = require('bluebird');

// var fields = ["youtube_id", "title", "date", "duration", "captioned", "views"];

var videos = [
  // More objects ~800+
];

promise
  .map(videos, function (v) {
    var url = 'https://youtu.be/';
    var options = {};

    if (v["captioned"] == 'No') {
      var url = url + v["youtube_id"];

      console.log(url);
      var options = {
        auto: true,
        all: false,
        lang: 'en',
        cwd: __dirname + "/auto_generated_captions",
      };

      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        youtubedl.getSubs(url, options, function (err, files) {
          console.log("did i get here?");

          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            console.log('subtitle files downloaded:', files);
            resolve(files);
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      // return a promise for this case
    }
  }, { concurrency: 5 })
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
```